# How to set a clicklistener to image in alertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have alertDialog with colors in it which is called from a button in my activity I need to set a listener to know which color the user select

```
private void colorDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom,null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    // Create and show the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

dialog_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/red_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/blue_circle"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/yellow_circle"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_blue" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/yellow_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_yellow"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/orange_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/yellow_circle"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/green_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/orange_circle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i know that i will need a While loop to track each color but i don't know how to set a clickListener to my alertDialog

thanks

Comment: Tried `dialogView.setOnClickListener`?

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper way of doing this in your case would , Implement as below:- Write a function like below in your activity

```
public void onClickOnColor(View view){

            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.red_circle:
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Red",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.yellow_circle:
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Yellow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.blue_circle:
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Blue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.orange_circle:
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Orange",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.green_circle:
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Green",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }
    }
```

And In dialog_custom.xml  for each view assign click listener **android:onClick="onClickOnColor"** see the below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/red_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        **android:onClick="onClickOnColor"**
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/blue_circle"/>
<View
        android:id="@+id/blue_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/yellow_circle"
   **android:onClick="onClickOnColor"**
        android:background="@drawable/circle_blue" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/yellow_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_yellow"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
   **android:onClick="onClickOnColor"**
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/orange_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
   **android:onClick="onClickOnColor"**
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/yellow_circle"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/green_circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        **android:background="@drawable/circle_green"**
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
   **android:onClick="onClickOnColor"**
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/orange_circle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this

```
private void colorDialog(){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom,null);
                dialogView.findViewById(R.id.yourButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                });
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                // Create and show the AlertDialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
```

Comment: dialogView.findViewById(R.id.yourButton) what is the purpose of this part i need to set the listener to the images in the alertdialog ?

Comment: You will set click for all buttons you want

Answer (score 0):

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new 
       View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.blue_circle : //do sth 
          break;
     case R.id.orange_circle : //do sth 
          break;
     case R.id.green_circle : //do sth 
          break;
     case R.id.red_circle : //do sth 
          break;
     case R.id.yellow_circle : //do sth 
          break;

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After building your dialogView :

```
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.red_circle).setOnClickListener(this);
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.blue_circle).setOnClickListener(this);
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.yellow_circle).setOnClickListener(this);
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.orange_circle).setOnClickListener(this);
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.green_circle).setOnClickListener(this);
```

After your class implements View.OnClickListener :

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.red_circle:
            Toast.makeText(this, "red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.blue_circle:
            Toast.makeText(this, "blue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.yellow_circle:
            Toast.makeText(this, "yellow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.orange_circle:
            Toast.makeText(this, "orange", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.green_circle:
            Toast.makeText(this, "green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```